# while loop and if not getting along with readdir() in C

Tags: c

While trying to write a program that will search a directory and list out contents matching a command line argument, I've come across a problem I can't seem to figure out.

I've put an if statement within a while loop to check whether the strings match, but the issue is that I only get the last entry in the directory back. If I comment out the if statement, it prints the entire directory just fine, and it matches strings just fine, but it won't do both.

A friend suggested it has something to do with the stack but as it is printing after each read, I don't see why that should be.

```
DIR *dirPos;
struct dirent * entry;
struct stat st;
char *pattern = argv[argc-1];

//----------------------
//a few error checks for command line and file opening
//----------------------

//Open directory
if ((dirPos = opendir(".")) == NULL){
    //error message if null
}

//Print entry
while ((entry = readdir(dirPos)) != NULL){
    if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, pattern)){
        stat(entry->d_name, &st);
        printf("%s\t%d\n", entry->d_name, st.st_size);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly then you want to use some regext API. strcmp doesnt match pattern but it does exact match with the string.

Comment: Obviously your program only prints one entry, because it prints the entry called <whatever is stored in pattern>, and two different entries can't have the same name.

Comment: Note: `stat()` needs the full path.

Comment: NulledPointer and immibis - using * as a wildcard seems to work, though. The problem is that it's only returning one result. For example, *.c prints main.c, but not functions.c.

Comment: joop - I've just started using stat() and don't quite understand?

Comment: The name "pattern" makes me wonder: are you expecting wild-card *.h patterns to work here? They don't.  Not sure how "*.h" would match anything unless you had a file named "*.h" .

If you are on GNU C, see fnmatch() or more general http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088/Wildcard-string-compare-globbing

Answer (score 0):

`entry` has to be defined as a pointer. `struct dirent* entry`. I compiled this on c and it works fine.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    DIR *dirPos;
    struct dirent* entry;
    struct stat st;
    char *pattern = argv[argc-1];

    //----------------------
    //a few error checks for command line and file opening
    //----------------------

    //Open directory
    if ((dirPos = opendir(".")) == NULL){
        //error message if null
    }

    //Print entry
    while ((entry = readdir(dirPos)) != NULL){
        if (!strcmp(entry->d_name, pattern)){
            stat(entry->d_name, &st);
            printf("%s\t%d\n", entry->d_name, st.st_size);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ended up changing entry to a pointer while I was spitballing and forgot to change it back, same result. *.c returns the last C file in the directory, and no others. *.h does the same with header files. *.c* returns main.c~

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect the current state of the program.

Comment: The OpenBSD manpage for opendir or readdir has that handy little loop, in Linux you have to look one up online.